Google Docs API with Python: Create different headers in each document section
I'm having a problem when trying to create a document with several sections in witch each section should have its own header title.
I'm able to create a document, add a text in body, add a header, add a text in header and create a new section.
But, as I create a new section, the header is inhered from previous section and i cant find a way to access and change only the header on the new section.
Here's my code (considering that i have already created a new document and have it's ID)
def insertText():
     """ Inputs text in the header. """

    insertText = {
        'insertText': {
            'location': {
                'index': 1
            },
            'text': 'Sample Body text'
        }
    }
    return insertText

def insertSectionBreak():
    """ Insert a section break at the end of document. """
    requests = {
            'insertSectionBreak': {
                'endOfSegmentLocation':{
                    'segmentId': ''
                },
                'sectionType': 'NEXT_PAGE'
                }
            }
    return requests


def insertHeader():
     """ Inserts text in the header """

    insertHeader = {
        'createHeader': {
        'type': 'DEFAULT'
        },
    }

    return insertHeader

def fillHeader(headerId):
     """ Inserts text in the header """
    fillHeader = {
        'insertText': {
            'location': {
                'segmentId': headerId,
                'index': 0
            },
            'text': 'Sample Header Text'
        }
    }
     
    return fillHeader



###################################################################################################

def insert_data(document_copy_id, creds):
    """ Calls other functions to the doc. """

    docs_service = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    fill_body_request = []
    create_header_request = []
    fill_header_request = []
    
    # document = docs_service.documents().get(documentId=document_copy_id).execute()
     
    # insert body text     
    fill_body_request.append(insertText())
    docs_service.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=document_copy_id, body={'requests': fill_body_request}).execute()
    
    # insert header and get its Id
    create_header_request.append(insertHeader())
    docs_service.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=document_copy_id, body={'requests': create_header_request}).execute()
    document = docs_service.documents().get(documentId=document_copy_id).execute()
    get_header_id = next(iter(document.get('headers', {}).values()))['headerId'] 
    
    # insert text in header
    fill_header_request.append(fillHeader(get_header_id))
    docs_service.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=document_copy_id, body={'requests': fill_header_request}).execute()

    # insert section break
    section_break_request.append(insertSectionBreak())
    docs_service.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=document_copy_id, body={'requests': section_break_request}).execute()


Running this code, i get a google document with "Sample Body Text" written in the first page, and a "Sample Header Text" written in both pages, even they are different sections.
Any ideas of how i could deal with it?

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? And, about a document with several sections in witch each section should have its own header title., what are sections and header? By the way, what is section_break_request`? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.
